# strange syntax in objective-c variable initialization

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I just saw this syntax in a SO answer, what is this called, and where in the Objective-C documentation is it defined?

```
self.backgroundView = (
{
    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    view;
});
```

I've never seen this before, or at least not noticed it, it seems to be an anonymous function. Normally blocks have a ^

Comment: It is a duplicate as far as I can tell.

Comment: Should be voted for dup. However, it is interesting feature.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) - the last thing evaluated in the `({ ... })` block becomes the result of the expression (`view` in this example). It's most commonly used for function-like macros.

Answer (score 1):

it is called [statement expression and is gcc extension to C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). It purpose is scoping. as soon as the variable is assigned, it is fully configured.

---

BTW:

```
self.backgroundView = (
{
    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    view;
});
```

in this example the property must be `strong` to work. but is not ideal for views, as the super view is holding it strong.

You should mark the property `weak` and do this:

```
UIView *backgroundView = (
{
    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    view;
});
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
self.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```

---

alternatively you can use implicitly declared blocks

```
UIView *backgroundView = ^{
    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return view;
}();

[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
self.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```

Comment: BTW the class in my trying this out is a UITableViewHeaderFooterView, the property is already defined.